# Path-App like round menu in Android

Tags: android

today I came across the Path App:
[image]

And wanted to ask if its possible to implement this round menu in Android. Would be a Framelayout a good solution or what would be better? Also I heard hat somebody had crated a library which implemented almost the same thing. But didn't found anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some open source projects that do it:

https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu - Apache 2.0

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/ - LGPL

Comment: Any idea on how to place the icon in the center, so that the other icons that are coming out of the click will surround the center one?

Comment: No idea, its in the screenshots of the first link so I assume its just a configuration option.

Comment: Any idea about that timeline watch that goes with the scroll??

Comment: @pKs That isn't within the scope of the question and I don't have an answer to it.

Comment: I know its not in the scope but I was mulling if you have an answer for it.

Comment: Pretty cool menu style, I've been trying to find something like this for angular with dynamic menu links. Any ideas?